# How to check a palindrome number without using a string?

Tags: python-3.x

Without using a string how to check if a number is palindrome or not.
Palindrome numbers are those which are read same from backwards also.
Ex- 121

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: I recently coded a program to check if the given no is palindrome or not but i coded it with the help of a string and i want to do it without the help of a string

Comment: Try some things, get a start, and post back when you have a specific question regarding code you've written. You'll want to use division and modulo though as a hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#The following method works fine:
def palindrome(n):

    divisor = 1
    # Find divisor to extract the leading digit
    while n / divisor >= 10:
        divisor *= 10

    while n != 0:

        leading = n // divisor
        trailing = n % 10

        # Check to see if first and last digit is equal
        if leading != trailing:
            return False

        # Remove the leading and trailing digit
        n = (n % divisor) // 10

        # Reducing divisor by a factor of 2 as 2 digits are dropped
        divisor = divisor / 100

    return True
```